# Delphi 2009 - How to fix 'undeclared identifiers' that are identified

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I have several custom components in my uses list of a unit.  For some reason, D2009 is saying that it cannot resolve the unit name.  But it seems as if it can find it - the code compiles fine.

How can I have it resolve the unit names at design time though?  My Structure window is showing all kinds of 'Undeclared Identifier' errors because the references in the Uses clause are not being found. This makes it difficult to code, and to debug legitimate errors in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is something the [IDE Fix Pack 2009/2010](http://www.delphifeeds.com/go/f/60696) can help you with.

```
RAD Studio 2009 fixes:
  <snip>
  QC #22880: Cannot resolve unit name
```

Comment: Unfortunately,I had to uninstall Fix Pack (long story). When I re-installed, it no longer fixes the problem I was having. No matter how many times I uninstall, then re-install, I'm still getting the same problem with Error Insight that I had previously.

Any ideas on how I can get IDE Fix Pack working again?

Answer (score 1):

Error Insight doesn't look for units the same way the normal compiler does, unfortunately, and it can lead strange results like that.  Try adding the units that your custom components are in to the DPR.  That should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have unit A and unit B, you call some methods in unit B from unit A, you can solve  the problem by the following steps.

1. first of all, clear "uses unit B" in unit A.
2. add your unit B to current project through "Add to project"
3. use unit B in unit A through "File/use unit", unit B will be added to unit A under 
   interface, the "Error undeclared identifier" disappear.

That is it!!!!