# Getting IDE Fix Pack 2 to work

Tags: delphi

On  [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460101/delphi-2009-how-to-fix-undeclared-identifiers-that-are-identified), someone recommended that I install Andy's [IDE Fix Pack](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=246) to get rid of an 'Undeclared Identfier' error in Error Insight with D2009.  It worked.

However, I had to uninstall it (long story).  When I re-installed, it no longer fixes the problem I was having.  No matter how many times I uninstall, then re-install, I'm still getting the same problem with Error Insight that I had previously.

Any ideas on how I can fix this problem with Error Insight?  Or get IDE Fix Pack working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDE fix pack does help with Error Insight problems, but also you can try closing the Delphi project, deleting any `.identcache` or `.local` files, and then re-opening the project. It seems to help when I get incorrect Error Insight, at least temporarily.

Comment: I have read about doing that; it seems that it gets varying results.  I did get my Error Insight working, but I'm not even sure how I did it.  Thanks for your help!